# Send JSON body but with ContentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded with ClientBuilder

Tags: java, jax-rs

I know the question is weird. Unfortunately I have a service that requires everything to have the header `ContentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, eventhough the body is JSON

I am trying to use JAX-RS 2.0 ClientBuilder to call it:

```
String baseUrl = "http://api.example.com/";

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put("key", "value");

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new LoggingFilter());
Builder builder = client.target(baseUrl).path("something").request();

Invocation inv = builder
    .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .buildPost(Entity.json(body));
Response response = inv.invoke();

int status = response.getStatus();
// I get 415, unsupported media type (in this case is unexpected)
```

I have checked my logs and I eventhough I am setting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (via the `MediaType`) the request appearantly has the `Content-type` of `application/json`

How can I force the request to have the `Content-type` I want?

---

BTW: This is my custom logger:

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "body");
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, requestContext.getEntity().toString());
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "headers");
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, requestContext.getHeaders().toString());
    }
}
```

And these are the logs I get:

```
com.acme.LoggingFilter                   I body
com.acme.LoggingFilter                   I {"key":"value"}
com.acme.LoggingFilter                   I headers
com.acme.LoggingFilter                   I {Content-type=[application/json]}
```

Comment: Ah, ok just use `Entity.entity("{..}", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM...)`. I _think_ that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with trying to use one of the static `Entity` helper methods is that it overrides any previous `Content-Type` header you may have set. In your current case, `Entity.json` automatically sets the header to `application/json`.

Instead of using the `.json` method, you can just use the general purpose `Entity.entity(Object, MediaType)` method. With your current case though, you can just do `Entity.entity(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)` though. The reason is that the client will look for a provider that knows how to serialize a `JSONObject` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which there is none. So you will need to first serialize it to a String. That way the provider that handles `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` doesn't need to serialize anything. So just do

```
Entity.entity(body.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
```